# How do I POST with multipart form data using fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am fetching a URL like this:

```
fetch(url, {
  mode: 'no-cors',
  method: method || null,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data) || null,
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.status)
  console.log("response");
  console.log(response)
})
```

My API expects the data to be of `multipart/form-data` so I am using `content-type` of this type... But it is giving me a response with status code 400.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

You're setting the `Content-Type` to be `multipart/form-data`, but then using `JSON.stringify` on the body data, which returns `application/json`. You have a content type mismatch.

You will need to encode your data as `multipart/form-data` instead of `json`. Usually `multipart/form-data` is used when uploading files, and is a bit more complicated than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which is the default for HTML forms).

The specification for `multipart/form-data` can be found in [RFC 1867](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt).

For a guide on how to submit that kind of data via javascript, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Using_XMLHttpRequest_and_the_FormData_object).

The basic idea is to use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object (not supported in IE < 10):

```
async function sendData(url, data) {
  const formData  = new FormData();
      
  for(const name in data) {
    formData.append(name, data[name]);
  }

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });

  // ...
}
```

Per [this article](https://muffinman.io/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/) make sure to **NOT set the** `Content-Type` **header**. The browser will set it for you, including the `boundary` parameter.

Comment: const fd = new FormData();
  // File to upload.
  fd.append('file', fileToUpload); fd.append('jsondatakey', 'jsondatavalue'); With this you will be able to send file along with some json data in body.

Comment: What if I need an Authorization?

Comment: Just set the authorization header like any other fetch request

Comment: Something like this will do it:
{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        body: formData
    }

Comment: Keep in mind that `name` in `formData.append(...)` call needs to be the name of the parameter that the Backend API is expecting. If it's not matching you will get **400 BadRequest** response. The second parameter can be a Blob as well or anything that derives from it as File.

Answer (score 39):

I was recently working with IPFS and worked this out. A curl example for IPFS to upload a file looks like this:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=CUSTOM" -d $'--CUSTOM\r\nContent-Type: multipart/octet-stream\r\nContent-Disposition: file; filename="test"\r\n\r\nHello World!\n--CUSTOM--' "http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add"
```

The basic idea is that each part (split by string in `boundary` with `--`) has it's own headers (`Content-Type` in the second part, for example.) The [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object manages all this for you, so it's a better way to accomplish our goals.

This translates to fetch API like this:

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('blob', new Blob(['Hello World!\n']), 'test')

fetch('http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Note about the above method, DO NOT supply headers if you do it using FormData because it will override the boundary thats automatically set.

Comment: Thanks @MattPengelly! How to set custom headers like Authorization then?

Comment: @DragosStrugar you can still set headers (Authorization included), just don't manually set the Content-Type header if you are using FormData.

Comment: DO NOT supply headers with 'Content-Type' if it's using FormData.

Comment: In the curl example, you need it. In the `FormData` example you don't need it, because the browser sends that header for you & also manages all the mime-boundries, which is the point of this solution.

Comment: I think supplying formData directly to the body like this is a much more elegant approach if you don't need to send additional data

Comment: @Brian Peterson: I agree. also it's not too bad even if you have other info to add: formData.set("field","value") for each other value (do it in a loop.)

Answer (score 2):

```
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('profile-image', document.getElementById("uploadDP").value);
            fetch('http://15.207.55.233/user/helper/profile-image', {
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                body: formData
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);                   
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
```