# Content type 'application/json' not supported

Tags: spring-boot

hi guys I am new to spring boot and I wanted to upload photo but I couldn't figure out what my problem is  can you help here is my controller and my service

I wanted to add the photo to new directory with path /src/main/resources/public/resources/file

````
package org.oib.controller;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import org.oib.controller.BaseController;
import org.oib.core.controller.response.AGPResponse;
import org.oib.model.ArtistModel;
import org.oib.service.ArtistService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/artist")
public class ArtistController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private ArtistService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getArtist() {
        return AGPResponse.response(service.getArtist());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
        
            public ResponseEntity<AGPResponse> handleFileUpload( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestBody ArtistModel Ar )  throws ParseException {
   
        String photo = file.getOriginalFilename();

        try {
            if (Ar.getId() == null) {
                 try {
                      file.transferTo( new File("/src/main/resources/public/resources/file" + photo));
                      service.addArtist(Ar);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
                    }  
                
            } else {
                service.updateArtist(Ar);
            }
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException ex) {
            return AGPResponse.error(getMessage("User Already Exist"), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);

        }
        return AGPResponse.success(getMessage("successful"));
    }
}

```ArtistService.java
````

package org.oib.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.oib.Mapper.ArtistMapper;
import org.oib.model.ArtistModel;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ArtistService {
@Autowired
private ArtistMapper arMap;

```
public List<ArtistModel> getArtist() {
    return arMap.getArtist();
}

public void addArtist(ArtistModel Ar) {
    arMap.addArtist(Ar);

}
```

```
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to upload the photo? The error sounds like your client tries to send json, instead of a multipart file.

Comment: you are right I tried to send  name and photo at the same time b/c I wanted my API to upload both multipart file and the description how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what you are using to send the files, but you can use this as guidance, if you are sending the request via JS: [multipart/form-data possible to send with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511744/multipart-form-data-possible-to-send-with-javascript)

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", "Smith");
formData.append("file", fileInputElement.files[0]);
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
});
```

For a better understanding of the server-side please refer to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart).
Especially the part about [handling programmatic clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms-non-browsers), if you are not using javascript for sending the data.

Comment: tnx for your help and sorry for not defining early what i am using in the client side that would have solved the complexity  anyways I am using Angulajs i will refer accordingly