# how send file and json, in react native using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

**I need to send a request to the server from ReactNative js to this result was how do I do?**

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"test", "email"=>"test@test.test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "repeat_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "telephone"=>"123456789", "location"=>"bla bla blalaldlval", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f76fd47b910 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170503-4-k6vif.jpg>, @original_filename="01858.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"01858.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}
```

**i try so**

```
static async createUser(paramsUser) {
  let response = await fetch('http://test.herokuapp.com/users', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
     user: {
      username: paramsUser.username,
      email: paramsUser.email,
      password: paramsUser.password,
      telephone: paramsUser.telephone,
      location: paramsUser.location,
      avatar: paramsUser.avatar, // this is image
     }
    })
  });
  return response = JSON.parse(await response.text())
}
```

**but his only json and how send for file?**

Comment: Send `formdata` instead of json in `body`'s value.

Comment: I tried but can not go tell exactly how to send formdata?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/fetch-post-with-multipart-form-data

Comment: You can send data with json, it just takes more time to complete. Insert base64 data to it.

Comment: base64 this is a very long and not very cool

Comment: @БогданЛитвин Did you get any solution on this? I'm facing the same issue between react-native and an API in Rails

Comment: @jandresrodriguez Hi, unfortunately no(