# Using ReactJS Fetch with an oData Batch request

Tags: reactjs, odata, batch-processing

we are using ReactJS with an oData service..and all of our single 'fetch' calls are working just fine but I need to figure out how to submit a batch request using the React 'fetch'

Have any of you been successful in doing this?

Comment: I believe I have found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/fetch-post-with-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful, but the problem is that FETCH and IE are not friends.

Basically you have to write a parser that will separate the batch response into the individual responses so that you can process them.

I have written the function packBatch() and unpackBatch() that provides and parses the post/response bodies of the batch request.  oData provides that format that you need to follow.