# Multipart post a file from URL using fetch

Tags: javascript, post, blob, fetch, multipartform-data

If this is a duplicate question, please link me to the appropriate place. I've looked and been unable to find what I need.

The title says it all. I have a direct url to a file. I need to make a multipart post using fetch. I understand I need to use blobs(?), but I have not been able to figure out the correct way to do this yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35206069/5378743

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. Why don't you just send the url to your server and fetch the file from there?