# Sending files in Reactjs Dropzone using multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I am working on an React application using a Dropzone npm package, which allows users to select multiple files. I would need to send these files as a multipart/form-data to my web service.

I don't have Form to post the data, I am using the an Ajax post request to send files to my WCF service.

I have configured the WCF to receive files as stream and I can successfully send files via PostMan as form-data in the body. But just trying to figure out how I can send my Dropzone files as multipart/form-data in the react app.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have Form to post the data

Why not? As shown in the docs [here](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage) you need to create a basic form like:

```
<form action="/file-upload"
  class="dropzone"
  id="my-awesome-dropzone">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

In case you create [Dropzone programmatically](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically), that should already be present.

Having that, sending the Files via Ajax is easy, since all you need to do is:

```
//create a FormData Object
//that will care about all
//the mimetypes etc
const fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('my-awesome-dropzone'));

fetch(<url>, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: fd
}).then(function (response) {
  //...
});
```

as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/fetch-post-with-multipart-form-data). Not using a `<form>` cannot work, since you do not have a `<input type="file" />` to give the user the opportunity to select files. Not taking advantage of using `FormData` is possible, but since that is complicated and error-prone, the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) was introduced.

That said, all you need to do is add [event listener(s)](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events) to the dropzone object and do what is need to be done.

The simplest form to perform an React Integratio is to use `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle methods to create and destroy the dropzone object. The needed form can be created within the `render()` method or, when used programmatically, with the callback of a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In my react .tsx file, although there is no <form> tag being using, I am using dropzone component like this: 
<Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)} >
            <p>drop files here</p>
          </Dropzone> and it does generate an <input type="file" /> tag upon page render. Could I use data from this input tag and use in the FormData.append() method?