# Laravel 5.4 $request->file() returns null

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fetch

I'm trying to save multiple files, but the Request file() method is returning null. Help-me please

My front end:

```html
        <input type="file" name="arquivos" multiple />
```

External JS:

```js
...
var form = document.forms['frmDados'];
...
```

In one function:

```js
...
        var formData = new FormData();

        var ins = form.elements['arquivos'].files.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
            formData.append('arquivos[]', form.elements['arquivos'].files[x]);
        }

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/fetch-post-with-multipart-form-data
        await fetch(window.location.href, {
            method: method, // POST or PUT
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': form.elements['_token'].value
            },
        }).then((response) => {
...
```

My backend:

```php
        $arquivos = $request->file('arquivos'); // Illuminate\Http\Request
        Log::info($arquivos);
        Log::info($request->all());
```

My laravel.log: (I uploaded 2 files, but only shows 1 in the all() method)

```php
[2020-04-07 14:40:11] local.INFO:   
[2020-04-07 14:40:11] local.INFO: array (
  'otheratribute' => '3',
  'otheratribute2' => '1',
  'otheratribute3' => '2020-03-03',
  'otheratribute4' => '03:00',
  'otheratribute5' => 'Tetandos',
  'otheratribute6' => '1',
  'otheratribute7' => '2020-04-01',
  'arquivos[]' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'jgcjkpmefepjgcpg.png',
     'mimeType' => 'image/png',
     'size' => 392328,
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

What I intend to do:

```php
         try {
             $infracao->upload($arquivos, true);
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
             return response($e->getMessage(), 503);
         }
```

**UPDATE 07/04/2020 18:21 GMT-3**

I forgot to specify, this solution worked for POST Request, but not for PUT Request which is [my problem, which is this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457) and [my beginning of solution is this](https://gist.github.com/Stunext/9171b7a8f3633b0b601a0feb8088dca1).

I'm using the solution as middleware, and the result for the request is what I put in the question.

Comment: Does `foreach ($arquivos as $arquivo) {Log::info($arquivo);}` help?

Comment: does not enter the loop, as $arquivos is empty

Comment: Try first with `<input type="file" name="arquivos[]" multiple />` maybe (also set other code accordingly)?

Comment: it didn't work, even adding [] everywhere where there are `$arquivos` the only thing I got was `[2020-04-07 17:05:40] local.INFO: /tmp/sfyTLOnk0` to `Log::info($request->file('arquivos[]'));`

Comment: `/tmp/sfyTLOnk0` could be temporary file.

Comment: Hey friends, I forgot to specify, this solution worked for POST Request, but not for PUT Request which is my problem, which is this: github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457 and my beginning of solution is this: gist.github.com/Stunext/9171b7a8f3633b0b601a0feb8088dca1 I will edit the question to specify

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do

```
$request->arquivos
```

instead of

```
$request->file('arquivos')
```

And probably you could also do

```
$request->input('arquivos')
```

Comment: I would like to emphasize that for the other attributes this works, less for the files

Comment: Hey friends, I forgot to specify, this solution worked for POST Request, but not for PUT Request which is my problem, which is this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457 and my beginning of solution is this:
https://gist.github.com/Stunext/9171b7a8f3633b0b601a0feb8088dca1 I will edit the question to specify