# Network request failed when fetch post with multipart form data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

I've tried following https://stackoverflow.com/a/40714217/9957948 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35206069/9957948 with no success.  I am still getting `Network request failed`.

Here is my cURL request that works:

```
curl -X POST "url" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--CUSTOM" -H "Content-Length: 237" -d $'----CUSTOM\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="fileToUpload"; filename="t006"\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\n\nset shiftwidth=4\nset autoindent\n\n----CUSTOM\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"\n\nUpload Image\n----CUSTOM--\n'
```

And here is what I tried to convert it to, and it is returning `Network request failed.`

```
uploadFile(){
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('blob', new Blob(['set shiftwidth=4\nset autoindent\n']), 't006')

        fetch('url', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error:' + error.message);
        })
```

Is `Content-Length` or the body `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` required?

I'm fairly new to all this so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: it's hard for me to reproduce your example. do you have a working `url` I could use?

Comment: What does the Network tab in the browser's developer tools show? Is it making the request you expect? Are there any other error messages reported on the Console? (It it perhaps failing with a preflight OPTIONS request?)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use PUT instead of POST method. Add **FLIPPER_VERSION=0.41.0** in your gradle.properties. If this does not work then comment a code from ReactNativeFlipper.java class path to this file yourProject\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\debug\java\com\facebook\flipper. [image: comment this code path to this file yourProject\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\debug\java\com\facebook\flipper]

Comment: You may need to provide header also
headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },