# fetch does not send post data

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I have the following js snippet:

```
    fetch('/some/webhook', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({test:'1'})
    }).then(function(res) {
        // do something here
    }).then(function(data) {
        // do something else here
    });
```

For hours I am trying to get the body to my server, but the listening script sees nothing in the $_POST variable. The webhook receives the request. A simple:

```
die (var_dump($_POST));
```

results in an empty array shown in the console where I would have expected to see the variable `test` with value 1.

What is wrong?

Comment: I highly recommend you to add to the post the tag of the backend language. It is PHP?

Comment: Maybe it is because of CORS. Can you open the browser console and check for errors at client side too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/fetch-post-with-multipart-form-data

Comment: @Aykhan: Nope, no issues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are sending your data, php will not populate de _POST variable

If you want to send `json` content, you should do

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

echo $data["test"];
```

Alternative solution, if you'd rather have your data in `_POST` you should send a `multipart/form-data` header and use a `new FormData();` as the body of `fetch`.

Comment: You were almost right, but it should be "input" instead of "stdin". Now working like a charm.

Comment: @Armin Hierstter : indeed, I mixed up, thanks for the edit