# I want to send Array of dictionary objects containing images though formData in Fetch/Axios

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, fetch

Hey i wana send this data with fetch, can anyone guide me how to?

```
{
    "User": "irjhiosd@#Dsadm",
    "name": "Some Name Here"
    pictures : [
       { picture : @PICTURE_FILE_HERE },
       { picture : @PICTURE_FILE_HERE },
       { picture : @PICTURE_FILE_HERE }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It largely depends on how the server is expecting the data to be structured

Comment: @Quentin exactly. If it's multipart, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/fetch-post-with-multipart-form-data

Comment: the server expects files to be sent in form data this is Django Standard API

Comment: @p32094 the problem is normally u can append form data with key and value, my usecase value is an array with json objects containing files which m not sure how to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});

let imageArray = []
// SAY U HAVE PICTURES IN A 'pictures' ARRAY
pictures.forEach((picture)=>{
    imageArray.push(  {'picture' : picture})
})
fields['pictures'] = imageArray

// After this u can normally send feilds as body in your fetch / axios request
```