# Relay Modern BadRequestError: Missing multipart field ‘operations’

Tags: graphql-js, relay, express-graphql, relaymodern

I am trying to upload file to my server. using Altair i can do it without any error but when i use Relay.js for uploading it server throws following error.

```
BadRequestError: Missing multipart field ‘operations’ (https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec).
at Busboy.<anonymous> (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/truck.pe__server/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql-upload@9.0.0_graphql@15.3.0/node_modules/graphql-upload/processRequest.js:362:11)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:326:22)
at Busboy.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
at Busboy.emit (/home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/truck.pe__server/node_modules/.pnpm/busboy@0.3.1/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:37:33)
at /home/dotsinspace/Documents/dev/truck.pe__server/node_modules/.pnpm/busboy@0.3.1/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:52:13
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Following are my graphql code and mutation which i am trying to commit.

#Graphql

```
graphql`
mutation AccountUploadMutation($profilePicture: Image!) {
    AccountUpload(profilePicture: $profilePicture) {
        message,
        status
    }
}
```

`

#Mutation

```
commitMutation(Environment, {
'mutation': AccountUploadMutation,
'variables': { 'profilePicture': v },
'uploadables': { 'file': v },
'onCompleted': (response, error) => Response({}, { response, error })
```

})

and I am totally confused about uploading part to..in uploadables you have to provide file..but my server looks for variable with profilePicture as image how can i deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue the multipart parsing configuration in your backend.

My guess is that the Relay [`Network`](https://relay.dev/docs/en/network-layer) is sending your GraphQL query in the mutlipart field "operation", but your backend is looking for the field "operations" (plural). To fix the error, confirm that your `Network` is sending the query in the `operations` field, or change your backend to read whatever field it's actually being sent on.

Another possibility is you're not sending your query in the multipart format at all. If you followed the `Network` documentation's example for sending your request, then you are just sending a JSON object, not a multipart form:

```
// Example from Relay docs. Sends a JSON object, not a multipart
// form as expected by your backend

function fetchQuery(
  operation,
  variables,
  cacheConfig,
  uploadables,
) {
  return fetch('/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      // Add authentication and other headers here
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: operation.text, // GraphQL text from input
      variables,
    }),
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
}

// Create a network layer from the fetch function
const network = Network.create(fetchQuery);
```

If this is the case, write your `fetchQuery` function to fetch data using a multipart form. See this example: [fetch post with multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/fetch-post-with-multipart-form-data)

Comment: Ok...Now i have checked my query and relay is sending request in operation field as you said in 1st point now my server is graphql-yoga server which has graphql-upload inbuilt and it can handle upload by default if i use altair or apollo client for same it works only relay is there which is causing error.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean. Are you doing multipart form uploads?

Comment: Dimitry I did some work around get file upload working. now its working but there is one problem. RN is uploading file in object format which contains. which is something like this. { 'fileName': Promise{ <pending> }... } but after doing PromiseAll(UploadedObject) all object value are null...and second its a workaround but i still need my uploaded multipart object to be in createReadStream form..not regular object. which is uploaded to server