# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed in react native

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data, multipart

I am new to react native. I have crated a form. from this form I am uploading images to server. But the problem not a single data uploading to server.  So what is problem is my code is wrong or what please help . I am not getting any specific error. please help. thanks. and my other forms is submitting properly they have not any images to upload but only problem with this form becuase here is images to upload

here is my code

```
export default function Add(props) {

  const { navigation } = props

  const [singleFilePAN, setSingleFilePAN] = useState('');
  const [singleFileADH, setSingleFileADH] = useState('');
  const [singleFileADH1, setSingleFileADH1] = useState('');
  const [singleFileSIGN, setSingleFileSIGN] = useState('');
  const [imageArray, setImageArray] = useState({
    PAN: null,
    GST: null,
    ADH: null,
    ADH1: null,
  });

 const validateInputs = () => {

    console.log(singleFilePAN)
    console.log(singleFileADH)
    console.log(singleFileADH1)
    console.log(singleFileSIGN)
    
    if (singleFilePAN && singleFileADH && singleFileADH1 && singleFileSIGN != null) 
    {
    if (!/[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}/.test(PAN) && imageArray.GST === null){
      setPanError('Please Insert valid PAN Card Image \n And Valid Pan card number')
      return;
    }
    if (!/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/.test(GST))  {
      setGstError('Please Insert valid GST Number')
      return;
    }
    if (!/^\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}$/.test(ADH)) { 
      setAdhError('Please Insert valid Aadhar Card Image \n And Valid Adhar card number')
      return;
    }
    else 
    {

        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=submitting form data to api start+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
{

  const leadTagNumber = props.route.params.leadTagNumber

    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by",'leadTagNumber']).then(response => {

  const formData = new FormData();


formData.append('lead_tag_number',leadTagNumber);
formData.append('pan_card_number', PAN);
formData.append('gstin_number', GST);
formData.append('aadhar_card_number', ADH);
formData.append('idfy_pan_card_status', "Done");
formData.append('idfy_aadhar_card_status',"Done");
formData.append('entry_sorce', "App");
formData.append('created_by', response[1][1]);
formData.append('application_id', response[0][1]);
formData.append('is_active', "Y");
formData.append('is_deleted', "N");
formData.append('created_time', "");

formData.append('upload_pancard', 
  {
    uri: singleFilePAN,
    name: 'pancardImage.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpg/png'
  }
);
formData.append('upload_aadhar', 
    {
        uri: singleFileADH,
        name: 'upload_aadhar.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpg/png'
    }
);
formData.append('upload_aadhar_second', 
    {
        uri: singleFileADH1,
        name: 'upload_aadhar_second.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpg/png'
    }
);
formData.append('digital_signature', 
    {
        uri: singleFileSIGN,
        name: 'digital_signature.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpg/png'
    }
);

  fetch('https://nasdigital.tech/Android_API_CI/upload_multipart_data', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },

      body: formData

    })
    .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      Alert.alert("File uploaded");
      return response.json();
      
     
    });
  });
  // event.preventDefault();
  }
  //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++submitting form data to api end++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

      Alert.alert("success")
      return;
}
    }
  };

 const takePicture = async (type) => {
    if (camera) {

      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      });

      console.log(data.uri);
      const newImageArr = imageArray;
      if (imageType === 'PAN') {
        newImageArr.PAN = data.uri;
      }else if (imageType === 'ADH' && evenTry) {
        newImageArr.ADH = data.uri;
        setEvenTry((val) => !val);
      } else if (imageType === 'ADH' && !evenTry) {
        newImageArr.ADH1 = data.uri;
        setEvenTry((val) => !val);
      }
      setImageArray({...newImageArr});
      
      setShowCamera(false);
      setImageType('');
      setSingleFilePAN({ singleFilePAN: newImageArr.PAN});
      setSingleFileADH({ singleFileADH: newImageArr.ADH});
      setSingleFileADH1({ singleFileADH1: newImageArr.ADH1});
    }
  };


  const pickImage = async (type) => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    });

    console.log(result.uri);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      const newImageArr = imageArray;
      if (type === 'PAN') {
        newImageArr.PAN = result.uri;
      } else if (type === 'ADH' && evenTry) {
        newImageArr.ADH = result.uri;
        setEvenTry((val) => !val);
      } else if (type === 'ADH' && !evenTry) {
        newImageArr.ADH1 = result.uri;
        setEvenTry((val) => !val);
      }
      setImageArray({ ...newImageArr });
     setSingleFilePAN({ singleFilePAN: newImageArr.PAN});
     setSingleFileADH({ singleFileADH: newImageArr.ADH});
     setSingleFileADH1({ singleFileADH1: newImageArr.ADH1});
    }
```

please ignore this = I am new to react native. I have crated a form. from this form I am uploading images to server. But the problem not a single data uploading to server.  So what is problem is my code is wrong or what please help . I am not getting any specific error. please help. thanks

Comment: You setting Content-Type to application/json but you trying to send multipart/form-data probably. See here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/how-do-i-post-with-multipart-form-data-using-fetch

Comment: Form multipart you could also see something here -https://muffinman.io/blog/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/
Might be helpful

Comment: not working by adding content type - multipart please help what should i change in my code

Comment: Have you tried posting something to that API using Postman for example first?

Comment: <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4> this error is coming in postmann

Comment: they saying delete content type - multipart  like this = delete options.headers['Content-Type']; so how could I delete that in my code

Comment: If you cannot post from Postman - there can be an issue on server side, are you sure that is even working? You need to first understand in what format server is expecting the files and try that with Postman, once you successful with it - you can apply same things to the code.

Comment: ok thanku. i will see

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bad type of form data passed with image, if you won't pass type of data you want to send BE probably won't get it

instead of

```
{
    uri: singleFilePAN,
    name: 'pancardImage.jpg', <- don't add extenstion
    type: 'image/jpg/png' <- bad type 
}
```

```
{
    uri: singleFilePAN,
    name: 'pancardImage', 
    type: 'image/jpg' 
}
```

check all mime types here -> [MIME DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)