# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when using Multer

Tags: javascript, express, svelte, multer

This is the frontend code:

```
<script>

import {dataStore} from '../../stores/dataStore'; 
import { tokenStore } from '../../stores/tokenStore';
import refreshToken from './refreshToken.svelte'

let name;
let description;
let category;
let price;
let stock;
let url;
let token;

tokenStore.subscribe(value =>{
    token = value;
})

let bearerToken = `Bearer ${token}`;


async function postData(){
    try {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3100/api/products`, {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data',
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Authorization": bearerToken,
        },
        
        body:({name:name, description:description, category:category,price:price,stock:stock,url:url}),
    });
    dataStore.update(n=> n+1);
    return res.json();
    } catch (err) {
        refreshToken();
        console.error(err);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

```
<form class="flex flex-col space-y-4 p-2" on:submit|preventDefault={postData}>
   
    <input class="rounded p-1 text-gray-900" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" bind:value={name}>
    <input class="rounded p-1 text-gray-900" type="text" name="description" placeholder="description" bind:value={description}>
    <input class="rounded p-1 text-gray-900" type="text" name= "category" placeholder="category" bind:value={category}>
    <input class="rounded p-1 text-gray-900" type="number" name="price" placeholder="price" bind:value={price}>
    <input class="rounded p-1 text-gray-900" type="number" name="stock" placeholder="stock" bind:value={stock}>
    <input class="rounded p-1 text-gray-900" type="url" name="url" placeholder="url" bind:value={url}>
    <input id='file' type="file" >
    <button class="rounded p-2 bg-cyan-500  text-white mt-4" type="submit">Add Product</button>
</form>
```

And this is the controller of the request:

```
    const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, description, url, price, category, stock } = req.body;
    const newProduct = await Product.create({
      name,
      description,
      url,
      price,
      category,
      stock,
    });
    res.json(newProduct);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

And this is the route:

```
router.post("/", upload.single("file"), authMiddleware, createProduct);
```

When I am running the request trough Thunder Client, it works really well ,but when I try to test it in the browser, I get this error.
Can anyone help?

I am trying to post a product with name description and add an image. I ran trough a couple of errors, usually it would make the body null, but after trying to fix it, the request does not even work anymore.

**Edit 1**: I tried doing what someone advised me in the comments, it still does not work, even after using formData.

```
var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('description',description);
    formData.append('category', category);
    formData.append('price',price);
    formData.append('stock', stock);
    formData.append('url',url)
    formData.append('file',file)

    try {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3100/api/products`, {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data',
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Authorization": bearerToken,
        },
        
        body:formData,
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I POST with multipart form data using fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/how-do-i-post-with-multipart-form-data-using-fetch)

Comment: It didin't work, I tried using the formData but I get the same error.
Also, my body originally wasn't even using JSON.stringify so I don't think I had the same problem

Comment: Look at the resource being fetched. I'm 99% sure it will be a HTML 404 page (hence the `<` at position `0`), which is why parsing it as JSON fails.

Comment: You can generate code snippet for fetch in Thunder Client, may be use that code and test it.