# Why signUp is not working in my mern stack blog app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I am creating a mern stack blog app and after adding the profile image option to my SignUp component it stopped working. Here is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const SignUp = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    console.log(history)
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [proImg, setproImg] = useState('');

    const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData();

        data.set('username', username);
        data.set('password', password);
        data.set('proImg', proImg[0]);
    
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/signup', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },

            });

    
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
    
            // You can handle the success here, or check the response data
           
            const responseData = await response.json();
            history.push('/');
            console.log('Success:', responseData);
            alert('Registration Succesful');
        
            } 
            catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            alert('Registration err try again later')
        }
    };
    
    return ( 
        <div className="sign-up">
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>
            <form action="" onSubmit={handleSignUp} encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input 
                    type="file" 
                    required
                    onChange={(e) => setproImg(e.target.files)}
                />
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Username"
                    required
                    value={username}
                    onChange={(e)=> {setUsername(e.target.value)}}
                    min={'4'}
                    max={"35"}
                />
                <br />
                <input 
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password" 
                    required
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}
                 />
                <br />
                <button>Sign Up</button>
            </form>
            <p>Already have an account? <Link to='/login'>Sign In</Link></p>

        </div>

     );
}
 
export default SignUp;
```

index.js(backend) :

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/User');
const Blog = require('./models/Blog')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieparser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const uploadMiddleware = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const fs = require('fs');

const saltRounds = 10;
const secret = 'hdskjfj49353kjdfsdjf';
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/BLOGAPP').then(()=> {
    console.log('Connected to mongo DB');
    app.listen(4000)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})

app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}))
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))

app.post('/signup', uploadMiddleware.single('proImg'),(req, res)=> {
    const { originalname, path } = req.file; // Change from req.proImg to req.file
    const part = originalname.split(".");
    const ext = part[part.length - 1];
    const newPath = path + '.' + ext;

    fs.renameSync(path, newPath);

    const {username, password} = req.body;
    const user = new User ({
        username, 
        password:bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds),
        proImg : newPath,
    });
    user.save()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Registration successful' });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    });
});

app.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
        // User not found
        res.status(400).json('User not found');
        return;
    }
    const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    if (passOk) {
        jwt.sign({ username, id: user._id }, secret, (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
            } else {
                res.cookie('token', token).json({
                    id: user._id,
                    username,
                })               
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json('Wrong credentials');
    }
});


app.post('/logout', (req, res)=> {
    res.cookie('token', '').json('ok')
})

app.get('/blogs', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const blogs = await Blog.find()
            .populate('author', 'username')
            .sort({createdAt : -1})
            .limit(20);
            res.json(blogs);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.cookies;

    if (!token) {
        // Token not provided
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT must be provided' });
        return;
    }

    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            // Invalid token
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
        } else {
            res.json(info);
        }
    });
});


app.post('/new_blog', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    const {originalname, path} = req.file;
    const part = originalname.split(".");
    const ext = part[part.length -1];
    const newPath = path+'.'+ext;
    fs.renameSync(path, newPath);

    // Check if token exists
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    if (!token) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT must be provided' });
        return;
    }

    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            return;
        }

        const { title, snippet, content } = req.body;

        const blog = new Blog({
            title,
            snippet,
            content,
            file: newPath,
            author: info.id,
        });

        try {
            // Save the blog and wait for the promise to resolve
            const savedBlog = await blog.save();
            res.json(savedBlog);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const Details = await Blog.findById(id).populate('author', ["username"]);

    if (!Details) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Blog not found' });
    }
    res.json(Details);
});

app.put('/blogs/:id', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const newPath = req.file ? req.file.path : null;

    const { token } = req.cookies;
    res.send(token)
    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            return;
        }

        try {
            const { title, content, snippet } = req.body;
            const blog = await Blog.findById(id);

            if (!blog) {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'Blog not found' });
                return;
            }

            // const isAuthor = blog.author.toString() === info.id;

            const isAuthor = JSON.stringify(blog.author) === JSON.stringify(info.id)

            if (!isAuthor) {
                res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
                return;
            }

            blog.title = title;
            blog.content = content;
            blog.snippet = snippet;

            if (newPath) {
                blog.file = newPath;
            }

            const updatedBlog = await blog.save();
            res.json(updatedBlog);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    });
});

app.delete('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const blog = await Blog.findById(id);
        // await /;

        const { token } = req.cookies;  
        console.log(token)

        jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            }

            const isAuthor = JSON.stringify(blog.author) === JSON.stringify(info.id);


            if (!isAuthor) {
                return res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
            }

            // Remove the associated file (if it exists)
            if (blog.file) {
                fs.unlinkSync(blog.file);
            }

            await Blog.findByIdAndDelete(id);
            return res.json({ message: 'Blog deleted successfully' });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
```

User.js(model):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min:4 ,
        max: 35,
        unique: true,
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    proImg : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min:4 ,
        max: 35,
        unique: true,
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    proImg : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

I was trying to create a signup option for my mern stack blog app but after adding the proImg to my sing up component and backend it stopped working.

And it's saying:

```
Multipart: Boundary not found
    at new Multipart (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:233:13)
    at getInstance (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\busboy\lib\index.js:33:12)
    at module.exports (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\busboy\lib\index.js:56:10)
    at multerMiddleware (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:28:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (D:\MURTAZA\projects\MERN STACK\1(Blog-site)\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

Comment: Hello, your issue is related to the fact that you set the header multipart without specifying a boundary. Check this thread to check how to send multipart data : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192841/how-do-i-post-with-multipart-form-data-using-fetch